# Replacement for Hermann Zapf's Aldus typeface

Tags: typefaces

Is there a good and **free** replacement for Hermann Zapfs Aldus typeface out there?

Right now I'm using the tgpagella in combination with helvet package but sometimes it seems a little bit too bold.

Comment: Zapf is my favorite typographer.  While Aldus bears some resemblence to Palatino, there are marked differences discussed at http://typophile.com/node/69809.  I am not aware of any public-domain clones of Aldus, unlike Palatino (for which there is Palladio).  More Zapf fonts can be viewed at http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-26201.html

Comment: Similar fonts may be located at Identifont: http://www.identifont.com/similar?HXK . 30 such fonts are identified as similar to Aldus.  However, the similar fonts are not necessarily free either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fonts and/or licenses, not using these with TeX.